# Feign UnsatisfiedDependecyException when running my spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some feign clients that I writed for my spring boot app

Here is my code

First here is a controller that where I use my feign client

```
package demo.notification;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import demo.shema.Feign.NotifFeignClient;
import demo.shema.dto.NotificationDTO;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(NotificationRestMediator.API)
public class NotificationRestMediator {
    public static final String API ="notif";

    @Autowired
    private NotifFeignClient notifFeignClient;

    @GetMapping
    List<NotificationDTO> getAllNotifications(){
        return notifFeignClient.getAll();
    }
}
```

then My feign client is as below

```
package demo.shema.Feign;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import demo.shema.dto.NotificationDTO;

@FeignClient("Notification")
public interface NotifFeignClient {

    public static final String NOTIF = "notif";

    @GetMapping(NOTIF)
    List<NotificationDTO> getAll();

    @PutMapping(NOTIF)
    Boolean setNotif(@RequestBody NotificationDTO notif,@RequestParam String principal);

    @PostMapping(NOTIF)
    NotificationDTO createNotif(@RequestBody NotificationDTO notif,@RequestParam String principal);

    @DeleteMapping(NOTIF)
    Boolean deleteNotif(@RequestParam Long notifID,@RequestParam String principal);

}
```

My feign configuration is on the main class using annotations and another config class as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients(basePackageClasses = { AppClientFeign.class })
@RibbonClients({ @RibbonClient(name = "COMPONENTS"), @RibbonClient(name = "USERS-MANAGER") })
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { ClientApplication.class , AppClientFeign.class })
```

then the class config is

```
@Configuration
@EnableFeignClients
@ImportAutoConfiguration({RibbonAutoConfiguration.class, FeignRibbonClientAutoConfiguration.class, FeignAutoConfiguration.class})
public class FeignConfig {

}
```

then the exception error detail is as below

> Error creating bean with name 'notificationRestMediator': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'notifFeignClient'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'demo.shema.Feign.NotifFeignClient':
>   FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: RequestParam.value() was empty on
>   parameter 1

What to do ?

Comment: i think this is bug, can you try in this way `Boolean setNotif(@RequestBody NotificationDTO notif,@RequestParam("principal") String principal);`

Comment: please add your comment as answer, and the explanation that I was using spring boot 2.x in some project using latest feign dependecies where requestParam value is not mandatory, but after refactoring to spring boot 1.5.6 this become mandatory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/1482), as you said for latest version don't need to specify value, but for older versions need to specify the value

```
@PutMapping(NOTIF)
Boolean setNotif(@RequestBody NotificationDTO notif,@RequestParam("principal") String principal);
```